# System.Windows.Interactivity.dll foreign folders

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, compilation, blend

We added reference to System.Windows.Interactivity.dll.
After compilation it added many folders with foreign languages resources.
How can we prevent this?
I know I can delete it from Blend folder but I prefer to keep the resources in Blend and
to prevent it from coping during compilation.
Does anyone have a solution to the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926363/visual-studio-2010-why-all-the-foreign-language-folders).