# When compiling WPF application language folders are copied to build folder

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

How can I cancel this option (I need only English).
Is it some installation that should be removed? configuration?

folders created are: `de`, `en`, `es`, `fr`, `it`, `ja`, `ko`, `zh-Hans` `zh-Hant`

Working with Visual Studio 2015

references:

- System.Windows.Interactivity
- Microsoft.Expression.Interactions

Comment: What are you use in your project's references?

Comment: i added picture with references

Comment: Do you have `.resx` files in your project?

Comment: I bet you've looked here [visual-studio-2010-why-all-the-foreign-language-folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3926363/visual-studio-2010-why-all-the-foreign-language-folders)?

Comment: Thanks, that resolved the issue (I assumed there would some 'uninstall' option / properties update)

Comment: I still have this issue, and while I can see that there are workarounds, I'm still hoping for something other than a manual step where you delete files from a local installation on every machine involved in a project. I'm looking for a maintainable, clean solution. There really should be a way to tell Visual Studio that I'm not interested in these localizations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sup>Turning my comment as an answer:</sup>

The issue may come from `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Expression\Blend\.NETFramework\v4.0\Libraries` which contains localizable objects for build. If you delete it (keep a backup to be sure) it should solve your issue.

Comment: This seems to be no longer an option when using .NET6.0+ because this folder does not exist.

Answer (score 11):

I added this in my "post build event command line" which is a bit shorter than the example by Dr. C. Hilarius.

```
rd /s /q "de" "en" "es" "fr" "hu" "it" "ja" "ko" "pr-br" "ro" "pt-br" "ru" "sv" "zh-hans" "zh-hant"
```

Comment: I like your quick answer, yet prefer the explicit declarations by Dr. C

Answer (score 9):

None of the suggestions worked for me.

Instead, I added post build events to remove the offending directories:

```
RMDIR "$(TargetDir)de/" /S /Q
RMDIR "$(TargetDir)es/" /S /Q 
RMDIR "$(TargetDir)fr/" /S /Q
RMDIR "$(TargetDir)it/" /S /Q
RMDIR "$(TargetDir)ja/" /S /Q
RMDIR "$(TargetDir)ko/" /S /Q
RMDIR "$(TargetDir)ru/" /S /Q
RMDIR "$(TargetDir)zh-Hans/" /S /Q
RMDIR "$(TargetDir)zh-Hant/" /S /Q
```

Comment: Nice, it works
`
RMDIR "$(TargetDir)de/" /S /Q
RMDIR "$(TargetDir)es/" /S /Q 
RMDIR "$(TargetDir)fr/" /S /Q
RMDIR "$(TargetDir)it/" /S /Q
RMDIR "$(TargetDir)ja/" /S /Q
RMDIR "$(TargetDir)ko/" /S /Q
RMDIR "$(TargetDir)ru/" /S /Q
RMDIR "$(TargetDir)zh-CHT/" /S /Q
RMDIR "$(TargetDir)zh-CHS/" /S /Q
RMDIR "$(TargetDir)pt/" /S /Q
RMDIR "$(TargetDir)zh-HANS/" /S /Q
RMDIR "$(TargetDir)zh-HANT/" /S /Q
`

Answer (score 2):

In The case of linking in ZedGraph into your project, simply go to the path where ZedGraph is installed (being referenced from).  Delete all the unwanted folders from this location, then go back and rebuild your project. Don't forget to delete all the unwanted folders in your projects output folder so you can verify the rebuild indeed does not recreate the unwanted folders.